# Verification Best Practices

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization

My team of data specialists (non-developers) is developing a system to manage a workflow that is mostly internal. Can anyone offer insight into the best practices for authorizing the various components? I have been stitching an understanding together from various documentations and message boards, and want to make sure my frankensteined answer is correct.

The system is comprised of several interrelated components build through our GAFE platform, scripted to interact with each other and to communicate with the end users and administrators via email and a simple UI.

- 2 Google Forms, each with attached scripts
- 2 Google Sheets, each with attached scripts
- 2 standalone web apps (Google Apps Script)
  -one of which has an audience external to our domain and will see users per day numbering in the low thousands.

My understanding is that, given that only the forms and one of two web apps are for external audiences, I can get away without verifying any of the components so long as I run the external-facing app as myself. Is this correct? Are their reasons to verify any/all components that I'm not comprehending from the documentation?

Thank You!
Rhodie

Comment: The reason to verify code with Google, is for a situation where the user will be authorizing permissions to **their** data.  A Google Form that is filled out, isn't running code from the account of the user who is filling out the Form.  (A Google Form can trigger an "On Form Submit" event, but even then, if the code is running in your account, then the user submitting the Form doesn't need to authorize anything)  And a Web App running as yourself is not accessing data in the users account.  So, if that is your situation, then it's pointless to go through the verification process.

Comment: The issue is not about whether the audience is external or not, it's whether an Apps Script service is accessing their data or their account information.  The Google Form can collect the user account email without the user needing to authorize a permission.

Comment: Thanks @SandyGood. Very helpful. The question about internal v. external is based on this note from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification --"Review is not required for Apps Script projects whose owner and users belong to the same G Suite domain or customer."-- Meaning that since the app will hit users from outside our domain, it would require authorization if it were executing the app as the user. Setting the app to execute as me sidesteps these issues. Thanks again!

Comment: Please checkout [Are “Is it a good practice…?” questions off topic or opinion-based?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296542/1595451) (the same applies for questions asking for best practices)